# Laravel 8 unionAll() with orderBy does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, union-all

I have two models which need to get as union select. Simple unionAll works but if I need to order the result by selected column it does not work. Laravel code looks like

```
    $events = Event::select('id', 'event_name as name', 'publish_at', DB::raw("'EVENT' as type"))
        ->customer($id)
        ->orderBy('publish_at', 'asc');

    $news = News::select('id', 'name', 'publish_at', DB::raw("'NEWS' as type"))
        ->customer($id)
        ->orderBy('publish_at', 'asc')
        ->unionAll($events)
        ->orderBy('publish_at');
```

SQL dump of this coed looks like:

```
(
    select "id", "name", "publish_at", 'NEWS' as type
    from "news" where exists 
        (
            select * from "customers"
            inner join "news_customers" 
            on "customers"."id" = news_customers"."customer_id"
            where "news"."id" = "news_customers"."news_id" 
            and "news_customers"."customer_id" = 3
        ) 
    order by "publish_at" asc
)    
union all    
(
    select "id", "event_name" as "name", "publish_at", 'EVENT' as type
    from "events" where exists 
    (
        select * from "customers" 
        inner join "event_customers" 
        on "customers"."id" = "event_customers"."customer_id" 
        where "events"."id" = "event_customers"."event_id" 
        and "event_customers"."customer_id" = 3
    )
    order by "publish_at" asc
) 
order by "publish_at" asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to order the unioned result by the `publish_at` column.

```
$subQuery = $events->toSql(); // Get the SQL query from the $events query builder

$news = News::select('id', 'name', 'publish_at', DB::raw("'NEWS' as type"))
    ->customer($id)
    ->orderBy('publish_at', 'asc')
    ->unionAll(DB::table(DB::raw("($subQuery) as sub")))
    ->orderBy('publish_at', 'asc');
```

Comment: I am sorry the my solution worked fine. I missed the year value where was a difference between 2022 and 2023